# Why does this String when converted to an Integer print as Nil?

Tags: json, swift

In the following snippet of code I am calling an API to retrieve some data from a database.

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]

if let dict = json?["personalLeagueStats"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
    if let dataMostWinsAgainst = dict["leaguePersonalMostWinsAgainst"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
        let newdictMostWinsAgainst = dataMostWinsAgainst.first!
        let tempMostWinsAgainstUserName = newdictMostWinsAgainst ["member"] as? String
        let tempMostWinsAgainstNumber = newdictMostWinsAgainst ["winPercentage"] as? String
        let temp2number = Int(tempMostWinsAgainstNumber!)
        print (temp2number)
        self.mostWinsAgainstPlayer.text = tempMostWinsAgainstUserName
    }
}
```

The data (`winPercentage`) i believe is stored as an integer as my SQL statement returns a value of e.g 0.67

I want to display this value in my app as a percentage so in Swift I want to multiply it by 100.  Please don't ask why don't I do this in PHP as I am trying to learn Swift and would like to know the process for future reference.

It is my understanding that in the following the snippet when the value for `winPercentage` is stored, it is stored as a String in `tempMostWinsAgainstNumber`.

When I try and convert this to an integer (to then perform the math) and print the value it prints `nil`.

Why is this?

How can I convert the value stored in `["winPercentage"] into an integer so I can multiply it by 100?

Comment: `0.67` is definitely not an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `0.67` to a `Double`, not an `Int`.

```
let tempMostWinsAgainstNumber = newdictMostWinsAgainst ["winPercentage"] as? String
guard let temp2number = Double(tempMostWinsAgainstNumber) else {
    // the String could not be converted to a Double
}
print(temp2number)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked - why do we use 'guard' in this instance?

Comment: It's possible for a `String` to not be convertible to a `Double`. This initializer of `Double` is failable, meaning it returns an `Optional` version of itself (`Double?`). The `guard` statement is just one way to safely unwrap this optional value.

Comment: If you were to force unwrap the optional with a `!` like you had before, if the `String` could not be converted to a `Double`, the app would crash.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's new information. Many places in my app I have done the former, but I know better now!

Comment: @RDowns You should read the Swift language guide. It covers the basics like optionals, guard and basic data types.